# Why does Java execute all files in folder, including closed ones?

Tags: java, testing, project, execute

I am writing Java code. I was using the if conditions to read the input. When I tried to test the code, it executes all the files in the folder. I am also using IntelliJ idea.

It executes my current file and saved java files.

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific about what you mean (you can [edit] your question). What files are you talking about? What do you mean by "execute"? What does "closed" mean in this context? Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: We definitely need code, [mcve] would be best.  The only reason for Java to "execute all files" is because you wrote the code that way.

Comment: Are you using an IDE, or the command line?  What commands and arguments are you using to compile and run your program?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Somehow I believe you have a project in your IDE, and you want to execute a (java) file. The file/class you think about has a `public void main(String[]) method`, yet instead of this file some other file gets executed?

Very likely the first file you created with a main method was registered as the entry point in your IDE or project setup, and that is remembered when you trigger the `run project` action.

Instead you need to find the correct keystroke or menu item to `run file` to get the focused file to execute.

If, however you feel like the file is executed since compilation errors show up - well that is because all files get compiled in the background. You need to reconfigure the IDE to stop it doing that - but why would you want to? It does not harm if the compiler works in the background.